# Angular2/Typescript compilation error: property 'body' does not exist on type 'Response'

Tags: typescript

```
getVerificationCode(phoneNumber) {
        let url = `${remote}/auth/phoneNumber/${phoneNumber}`;
        return this._http.get(url)
            .toPromise()
            .then(result => {
               console.log(result.body);  <--- ERROR
            });
      }
```

In the above code when result returns, it has a property called body.
However the typescript compiler throws the following error:

```
Error TS2339: Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Response'.
```

Not sure quiet how to deal with this.

I tried defining an interface of type

```
interface ResultData<T> {
  body: string
}
```

and then using it as:

```
this.getVerificationCode('1111111') {
    let url = `${remote}/auth/phoneNumber/${phoneNumber}`;
     return this._http.get(url)
           .toPromise()
           .then( (result: ResultData<any> )=> {
                   console.log(result.body);  <--- ERROR
                });
```

but then I would get the following error:

```
Error TS2345: Argument of type '(result: ResultData<any>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Response) => void | PromiseLike<void>'.
  Types of parameters 'result' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'ResultData<any>'.
      Property 'body' is missing in type 'Response'.
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
getVerificationCode(phoneNumber) {
    let url = `${remote}/auth/phoneNumber/${phoneNumber}`;
    return this._http.get(url)
        .toPromise()
        .then((result: Object) => {
           console.log(result.body);  <--- ERROR
        });
  }
```